# On click display only elements that have the same data attr as it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of elements on a page, within each element there is a div with a data tag. Each element has a certain data tag value, and some elements have the same value.

I am trying to sort the elements based on the data tag value when the div is clicked. For some reason, I'm unable to figure the best approach. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".tag-pill img").on('click', function() {
        var tagClicked = $(this).attr("data-tag");
        $('#page-card .col-lg-4').hide();

        $('#page-card .col-lg-4').each(function() {
            if ($(this + '[data-tag="' + tagClicked + '" ]').length > 0) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        })
    })

});
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please include all relevant code(html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working snippet :

```js
const $set = $(".col-lg-4") // Cache for performance

$(".tag-pill img").click(e => {
  let tagClicked = e.target.attributes["data-tag"].nodeValue
  console.log(`tagClicked = ${tagClicked}`)

  $set.show() // Show all
    .find(`[data-tag='${tagClicked}']`) // Finds a subset
    .hide() // Hide the subset
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag-pill" data-tag="it works">
   <img data-tag="It works!" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" /> Click the image
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <p data-tag="It works!">Should disappear</p>
  <p data-tag="It works!">Should disappear</p>
  <p>Should remain visible</p>
  <p data-tag="It works!">Should disappear</p>
  <p>Should remain visible</p>
  <p data-tag="It works!">Should disappear</p>
</div>
```

Instead of a costly `$(this).attr()` (building a jQuery object on each click) you can natively grab the desired value using `e.target.attributes["data-tag"].nodeValue`

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. This throws an error to the console stating that ['data-tag'=undefined]...

Comment: Oh yes sorry. Thiwas because of the fat arrow function that was getting the global context and changing `this`. I reverted to `function()` and now it should work.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. This is close, however the result is that it hides the tags themselves and not each 'col-lg-4' that contains a tag with that value...

Comment: What? I don't get it. Isn't that what I'm doing? I'm hiding the `<p>` tags themselves inside `.col-lg-4`, aren't I?

Answer (score 0):

You can show like this,

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".tag-pill img").on('click', function() {
        var tagClicked = $(this).attr("data-tag");
        $('#page-card .col-lg-4').hide();

        $('#page-card .col-lg-4[data-tag="' + tagClicked + '" ]').show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".tag-pill img").on('click', function() {
        var tagClicked = $(this).attr("data-tag");
        $('#page-card .col-lg-4').hide();

        $('#page-card .col-lg-4').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("data-tag") == tagClicked) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        })
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any each for this, if i understand you correctly something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".tag-pill img").on('click', function() {
      var tagClicked = $(this).attr("data-tag");
      $('#page-card .col-lg-4').hide();
  /* 
  * show all elements with a specific data attribute
  */
  $('[data-tag="' + tagClicked + '" ]').show(); 
    })
 });
```